# Can I set up a docker-compose configuration with no networks?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use Docker Compose to configure some Dockerised batch jobs. These jobs pull some data from external databases and then save data back to other databases. The jobs never interact directly with each other. They do not expose any ports or run any servers.

I would like to switch off Docker networking.

By default, docker-compose [creates a network for each configuration](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/). Is there a way to supress this so that compose starts running the container without bothering to create any network?

Answer (score 5):

If you bothering the sole create/destroy process of the network you can create a network once and use it every time you spin the compose.

```
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: whatevernameyougaveit
```

In addition there is a docker built-in network called None, which disables networks completely for a container joining that. Maybe you already have seen it with `docker network ls` along with `host`

```
services:
  service:
   network_mode: none
```

If all services using a `network_mode` host or none, compose will suppress the creation of the default network..

**Edit**: One (including me) might have the idea to implement it like that to get rid of the `network_mode` setting for each service:

```
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: none
```

But then compose thinks it is actually a network and tries to set the network aliases which leads to an error: `network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks`. Same applies if you try to add the other pre-configured networks like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can tell docker-compose to use the host network for the containers. You define it for each container like this

```
services:
  myapp:
    image: asdf
    network_mode: host
```

Of course that means that any ports that the container uses need to be available on the host, since you can't do any port mapping.

Normally, the networks created are a nice thing and something you want to do. You may not realise it, but running a single container with `docker run` also creates a network, unless you use host network mode.

Comment: Personally I dislike adding containers to the host network due to some disadvantages like potential conflicts between containers and containers with services running on host os. Additionally security mechanisms are bypassed. But that depends on the use-case..

Comment: Yes. You didn't really explain why you don't want to create the network, so I just came up with a solution. The best thing is almost certainly to let docker compose create the network and attach the containers to it.

Comment: Wasn't my question. I just wanted to enlight both sides of the medal of this approach, even if it's a valid solution without knowing the motivation of the question. So no offending, your answer is also right, as I wrote: depends on use-case.

Comment: @HansKilian - the motivation for this: None of the processes expose any ports. They are just batches. Also, there's a bug in Docker-compose that sometimes creates duplicate network connections if multiple processes are fired up at the exact same time for compose configuration.

Comment: @HansKilian - what's the difference between what you propose and:
```
networks: {}
```

Comment: That ```networks: {}``` also creates a default network?